# User name "stackoverflow"

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

Is it a good idea to let users have the name '`stackoverflow`'?

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12178/stackoverflow

Comment: This has been [brought up on meta.stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125665/is-the-profile-username-stackoverflow-legal) before and the consensus seems to be that it's fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As sepp2k said, this has already been brought up on SO. There's no rules on avatar names, and there isn't any trolling or impersonation here. The official verdict [seems to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99914/what-are-the-rules-governing-display-names-and-avatars/99919#99919):

> AFAIK there is no official policy on user names, and the only one on avatars is that they should be PG-rated (i.e., nothing offensive).
>
> Users on SO aren't allowed to solicit other users, so if a fake Jon Skeet were trying to pull a con on another user in order to get something, that would be reason enough for action.
>
> Same goes if they were impersonating for the purpose of trolling. Trolling isn't acceptable here, so they can be dealt with.

So, there is no problem with this username.